# jquery load() will only load the html from the extermal page, no stylesheet or jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have two pages. For explanations sake I'll call them page A and Page B. When I open page B in my browser it is rendered with all the styling and jquery ui code working properly, but when I open page B inside of a div in Page A via the load() method, the only thing that renders is the raw html, no styling, no interfaces. What is the problem? Directly below is the code from page B and all the way at the bottom is the code from page A:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> //jquery ui

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://spilot.koding.com/lbStyle.css"/>  //stylesheet

 <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.2.min.js"></script> //parse database

   <script>

$(function(){
    var crowd = ' ';
    var ageGroup = ' ';
    var activity = [];
    var scene = [];
    var neighborhood = [];
    var date = [];
    var details = [];
    var time = [];
   Parse.initialize("ivHLAO7z9ml1bBglUNuPSgcWabXe3UeE2yCgKM2x","gNeGt04lU7xcew893EvbEJ05qqc4POVhBsIBSCVj");

   $(".menu").menu({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('.selected', this).removeClass('selected');
        var selection = ui.item.addClass('selected').children('a').attr('name'); //add background color to selected menu item and get its attribute name
        var choice = ui.item.text(); //get text of menu selection


         if(selection == "ageGroup"){
        $("#ageGroup").text(choice); //change the text in the first <a> of ageGroup menu to ageGroup selection. 
        ageGroup = $("#ageGroup").text();
        }else{
         crowd = selection;
        }; 

        } // closes select function


    }); // closes menu
     $("button").click(function(){

var city = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('city') ); 
var niche = Parse.Object.extend(crowd);
var query = new Parse.Query(niche);
query.equalTo("ageGroup", ageGroup);
query.equalTo("city", city);
//query.include([activity.date.details.location.neighborhood.time])
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    activity = results[i].get("activity");
    scene = results[i].get("location");
    neighborhood = results[i].get("neighborhood");
    date = results[i].get("date");
    details = results[i].get("details");
    time = results[i].get("time");

    };
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});

//alert("working");

}); //closes click() 

}); // close function()
</script>
 <script>

$(function(){
 $( "button" ).button(); 

});
    </script>

</head>

  <body>



 <div id="div1">

         <button>Button label</button>


<div id="div2">
 <ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="ageGroup">Age Group</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" name="ageGroup">18-21</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="ageGroup">21-30</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="ageGroup">30-40</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="ageGroup">40-50</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="ageGroup">50-60</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="ageGroup">60-70</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="ageGroup">70-80</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="ageGroup">80-90</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="ageGroup">90-100</a></li>
            </ul>

    </li>
    </ul>  

</div>   

<div id="div3">
        <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                <li><a href="#" name="academic_artStudies" id="academic_artStudies"><img src="" alt="" /><h2>Academic: Art Studies</h2></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" name="academic_Literature"><img src="" alt="" /><h2>Academic: Literature</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="academic_socialSciences"><img src="" alt="" /><h2>Academic: Social Sciences</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="academic_physicalNaturalSci"><img src="" alt="" /><h2>Academic: Physical/Natural Sciences</h2></a></li>

  </ul>

</div>

</div>



</body>
</html>

 --------------//PAGE A//--------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
$(function(){


$("#mainDiv").load("http://myURl.com/find2.html"); //this is where I call load()

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
       //this is the div where I want the other page to load

     <div id="mainDiv">

     </div> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are loading page "b" into page "a", you need to have all page "b" stylesheets/js in page "a" header.

please note that you are loading a complete html page into page "a", that includes html,header,body and that is not desirable, you should make page "b" a template that only contains the markup you need.

**UPDATE:**

1. you are embedding your scripts in the html, that is a bad practice, separate the JS code to different files.
2. When you include JS code in your file it will run as soon as the page loads, so if you put 'pageb' code in 'pagea' it will run as soon as 'pagea' was loaded and when you load 'pageb' the code will not run again.
3. You need to put 'pageb' code in a function and call it only after you loaded 'pageb' content.

Comment: now the problem is that since I moved the header code to page A, the other script on page B wont work. It still doesn't work even if I move that script to page A and only leave the markup on page B.